# Was Harry Potter the inspiration for Tommy Taylor?

Tags: harry-potter, comics, inspiration, the-unwritten

There are so many analogies between Tommy Taylor in the *Unwritten* comics and *Harry Potter* it seems unlikely to be a coincidence (Voldemort/the Count, the grouping and make-up of the two sidekicks, the school, professor, etc).

Has Mike Carey gone on record explaining the similarities, and whether it was actually a conscious choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike Carey address *Harry Potter* somewhat in [this interview](http://scifipulse.net/2009/06/comics-interview-uk-writer-mike-carey-on-his-career-to-date/):

> **Yanes:  Your most recent work has been The Unwritten.  I have yet to
>   read a negative review about this title.  How did you feel to get such
>   positive feedback?**
>
> **Carey:** It’s been great!  The scale and the strength of the response
>   were wholly unexpected, even given the one-dollar price point.  There
>   were one or two negative reviews, though.  Someone on iFanboy said
>   “Hey, this is a total rip-off of Harry Potter”.  Umm, yes.  Of course
>   it is.  Because Harry Potter is all about a real boy who suddenly
>   becomes the messiah of a lunatic cult and has to cope with the
>   possibility that he may be a fictional character…
>
> **Yanes:  The Unwritten does seem to be in part inspired by the Harry
>   Potter book series.  What other influences are you drawing from for
>   this title?  Beyond the works that influenced you, what was the main
>   inspiration in creating this story?**
>
> **Carey:** Probably the most important reference point is the
>   autobiography of Christopher Milne – who is famous as the Christopher
>   Robin of the Winnie the Pooh books.  Milne grew up feeling that his
>   father had stolen his childhood from him, turned a profit from it and
>   then given it back to him in a form he couldn’t use.  Our Tom is very
>   much in that situation when we first meet him, although we take his
>   identity crisis a fair bit further than that.
>
> But The Unwritten is a story about stories, and it has a whole sackful
>   of great stories embedded in it.  Frankenstein is a story we go back
>   to again and again, always from a different angle.  Moby Dick, the
>   Just So Stories, The Song of Roland, Gilgamesh…we’re very eclectic
>   with our borrowings.

and

> **Yanes:  Several commentators have compared your use of the acrostic
>   poem and cable news scroll to Watchmen.  And many have also compared
>   your homage to Harry Potter to The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen. 
>   What’s it like to be compared to Alan Moore?**
>
> **Carey:** I hadn’t read those particular commentaries, so all I can say
>   is…
>
> Actually, I can’t say anything.  I open my mouth to speak, nothing
>   comes out.

In [another interview](https://www.portlandmercury.com/BlogtownPDX/archives/2010/01/07/an-qanda-with-the-unwrittens-mike-carey) he says:

> **Why did you choose Harry Potter as your starting point?**
>
> We didn’t, really. We chose Christopher Robin from the Winnie the Pooh
>   books as our starting point. When we were talking about this idea,
>   about following a character both in fiction and in reality (we being
>   me and Peter Gross, the artist), it struck a chord with me, because
>   I’d read Christopher Milne’s biography—he’s the Christopher Robin from
>   Winnie the Pooh—and he grew up hating what his father had done, hating
>   the fact that he was famous as somebody else’s fictional character. So
>   that was our starting point. But when we started fleshing out the idea
>   and it became about celebrity and the sort of viral spread of ideas in
>   popular culture, we decided to choose a fiction that would have more
>   resonance for a modern audience. The character of the boy-wizard
>   seemed to be tailor made for us, really. Sorry, no pun intended.

...

> **How have Harry Potter fans have received your parody?**
>
> We haven’t had a backlash yet. It may come. There’s a kind of other
>   dimension to this for us, because for many years Peter drew, and wrote
>   some of the time, a series called The Books of Magic, where the hero
>   was a young, bespectacled wizard named Timothy Hunter. And he actually
>   draws Tommy as Tim Hunter. So we’ve kind of got multiple-boy-wizard
>   action going on. And it is kind of an archetype. That would be an
>   argument that I’d like to advance. Before Gaiman and before Rowling
>   you’ve got Diana Wynne Jones, you’ve got Jill Murphy’s Worst Witch at
>   School books, and so on. It goes a long way back.

To give a timeline to those mentioned by Carey (before anyone asks for details)

- 1974 - *The Worst Witch*
- 1977 - *Charmed Life* (Mmost likely the Diana Wynne Jones book he mentions)
- 1990 - *Books of Magic*

And of course

- 1997 - *Harry Potter*
- 2009 - *The Unwritten*

Comment: Wow, nice answer.  He never really addresses the similarities directly, but probably for good reason as DVK mentions. :)

Answer (score 3):

Count Ambrosio is probably more an analogy to Count Orlok from the film *Nosferatu* (1922) than Voldemort and Savoy is more an exploration of the

> modern Vampire trope

than a Weasley.